# Скрывать блок по умолчанию

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно чтобы по открытию страницы блок с айди price-wrapper был скрыт. С помощью JS реализовал показ и скрытие блока, но проблема в том что по умолчанию принимается не то значение и блок виден а не скрыт. Если уже в ручную снова изменить строку в dropdown, тогда блок скроется. Что делаю не так? Заранее спасибо.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-10 mx-auto mb-3">
            <select class="form-control access_idd" id="access_id" >
                <option value="0">Виден всем</option>
          <!--  <option value="1">Виден подписчикам</option> -->
                <option value="2">Платные просмотры</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="price-wrapper">

        <div class="col-sm-2 mx-auto mb-3">
            Стоимость просмотра
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 mx-auto mb-3">
            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="price" value="0" id="price">
        </div>
       </div>

$("#access_id").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == 2) {
                    $("#price-wrapper").show();
                } else {
                    $("#price-wrapper").hide();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$("#access_id").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 2) {
    $("#price-wrapper").show();
  } else {
    $("#price-wrapper").hide();
  }
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 mx-auto mb-3">
    <select class="form-control access_idd" id="access_id">
      <option value="0">Виден всем</option>
      <!--  <option value="1">Виден подписчикам</option> -->
      <option value="2">Платные просмотры</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" id="price-wrapper">

  <div class="col-sm-2 mx-auto mb-3">
    Стоимость просмотра
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 mx-auto mb-3">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="price" value="0" id="price">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Событие `.change()` происходит тогда, когда вы вручную меняете пункт из выпадающего списка. Оно не будет срабатывать, если вы просто загрузите страницу. Поставьте лучше для `price-wrapper` стиль `display: none`.